# JFXtras Classes and their Objects Explained

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

- ***What are the differences between the following JFXtras Classes?***
- ***What kinds of Objects do they create?***

  1. Agenda, Agenda.Appointment, Agenda.AppointmentGroup
  2. Agenda.AppointmentGroupImpl, Agenda.AppointmentImpl, Agenda.CalendarRange
  3. Agenda.AgendaSkin, AgendaWeekSkin

Thank you all in advance.

***PS.***

*I've been going over the **JFTras API**  but there's not much explanation there. There isn't that much elsewhere on the internet either.
I think the JFXtras framework could really grow; it seems really useful, especially the Agenda, plus it is just what I need for my project now.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:

- `Agenda` is a JavaFX calendar component
- `Agenda.Appointment`, `Agenda.AppointmentGroup` are interfaces
- `Agenda.AppointmentGroupImpl`, `Agenda.AppointmentImpl` are default implementations of previously mentioned interfaces
- `Agenda.AgendaSkin`, `Agenda.WeekSkin` are implementations of JavaFX component skins

More info on architecture of JavaFX component can be found at http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/

Comment: Thanks a lot [eugener](http://stackoverflow.com/users/112877/eugener). That helped a lot, especially [the Link](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/). Can't help but notice that you just bounced over to +10K! Congrats!

Comment: Yep.. just noticed it too. Cool number to see next my icon :)